# While loop takes too much time

Tags: java, oracle

This select statement returns 4k+ rows. What takes up time in my application is the while-loop. The loop alone takes 2 to 4 minutes. Any ideas on how to optimize it?

Don't worry much about the query itself as it doesn't take too much time on the query response.

```
ArrayList<MembershipMemberInterestsVo> list = new ArrayList<MembershipMemberInterestsVo>();
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
            sql.append("SELECT to_char(mai.id_info) as id, ");
            sql.append("to_char(mai.field_title) as title, ");
            sql.append("to_char(mmi.member_id) as membership_id ");
            sql.append("FROM memserv_member_interests mmi, memserv_add_info mai ");
            sql.append("WHERE mmi.interests like '%-' || mai.memserv_id || '-%' ");
            sql.append("AND mai.soc_body_id = ? ");
            sql.append("UNION ");
            sql.append("SELECT to_char(mit.interest_id) as id, ");
            sql.append("to_char(mit.text) as title, ");
            sql.append("to_char(mit.member_id) as membership_id ");
            sql.append("FROM memserv_member_interest_text mit ");
            sql.append("WHERE society_id = ?");

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            pstmt.setString(1, societyId);
            pstmt.setString(2, societyId);

            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            MembershipMemberInterestsVo vo = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                vo = new MembershipMemberInterestsVo();
                vo.setInterestId(rs.getString("id"));
                vo.setMembershipId(rs.getString("membership_id"));
                vo.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                vo.setSocietyId(societyId);
                list.add(vo);
            }
```

Comment: have you tried multithreading?

Comment: CPU on Java process rather than database high? Use a profiler. Doesn't look like there is anything specifically an issue within the while loop. I could imagine the SQL is slow if it isn't indexed.

Comment: Presizing the ArrayList should do a bit to alleviate your problems. The default size is 10 and it grows by (capacity * 3)/2 + 1. When it grows you have to copy the contents of the old array into the new array.I'm guessing the Membership* class isn't all that heavy?

Comment: One source of slowness might be that the ArrayList is constantly extending as you add more elements to it.  If you can guess at how many results are going to come back, initialize the list to be that big.

Or use a LinkedList, which has no overhead but does have other caveats.

Comment: Or switch to linked list.

Comment: Um. Multithreading? Really?? `ArrayList` is fast - O(n) for n inserts. 4K entries no problem. `LinkedList` will cause loads of additional memory allocations and should be slower.

Comment: Let me try switching to linkedlist..

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The problem that I am addressing isn't really the insert performance per se, it's that the array  list has to grow quite often as it is way too small to handle the number of entries. The array grows quite slowly which means that there are quite a few copy operations on the array.

Comment: I wouldn't use a StringBuffer when StringBuilder is an option.  In this case I would just use String concatenation.

Comment: We're talking about an estimated result set of 4,000 entries. Any list type should handle that in no time at all.

Comment: @Erik That isn't a problem. You are copying a *reference* I guess once or twice during the run. Block copying is really fast. Much faster than even the simplest implementation of your "Value Object" (correct term is Data Transfer Object - are you reading a really old book?).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Memory allocation time isn't really a major problem w. todays vm:s. Worse would be cluttering the gc with extra objects.

Comment: @Erik That's the marketing hype. No it doesn't look a problem here. But still `ArrayList` is **hugely** efficient.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline once or twice??? The algorithm for growth is cap*3/2 +1 and it starts at 10!

Answer (score 5):

The problem most likely is with your SQL statement. Adding 4,000 entries to a List, doesn't take any noticeable amount of time.

If this is not a typo

```
WHERE mmi.interests like '%-' || mai.memserv_id || '-%'
```

you end up with the whole table as a result set.

Comment: So ultimately it boils down to the data retrieval time :)

Comment: Thanks, will continue investigating and get back on this. Let me try suggestions from the comments above firs.t

Answer (score 0):

I guess its not the while loop, but the time to retrieve data from the database that must be taking considerable time - this is during iterating over the result set.

Do not create any object in the while loop, just iterate over the result set and see the time required. Should be nearly same.

Comment: nope. i tested that with breakpoints, the while loop is the one that takes too much time.

Comment: Did you test with empty while loop? what's the timing then? Only other possibility could be that some heavy operation is done in the constructor of MembershipMemberInterestsVo.

Comment: couple of thread dumps might help.check the stack to confirm if its spending time in data retrieval .

Comment: Time spent from data retrieval is minimal.